Does the cloglog link function correspond to a named distribution?
Common choices for a link function in a statistical model that maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0, 1)$ include logit, probit, and cloglog.
For logit models, the inverse link function is $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, which is the CDF of a standard logistic distribution. For probit models, the inverse link is the CDF of a standard normal distribution.
For cloglog models, the inverse link function is $1 - e^{-e^x}$, which results in a density function proportional to $e^{x-e^x}$. Is this a named distribution? A brief search for "cloglog distribution" or "complementary log-log distribution" only returned results for a cloglog model itself and nothing on the actual distribution.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gumbel+distribution  This thread shows one way in which it arises and illustrates its density function.

Thanks, this is what I was looking for, if you want to turn this into an answer I'll accept iy

Be careful nevertheless: you have to distinguish the "maximum extreme value" from the "minimum extreme value" versions of what someone calls a "Gumbel distribution." See this page, for example.
